# Calculate rectangle position after scaling from his center

Tags: geometry, transformation

I have a rectangle with these bounds

```
height: 31.010414123535156
width: 215.8330078125
x: 10.95849609375
y: 90.49478912353516
```

I want to scale up the rectangle by a `0.541667` factor.
X, Y coordinates are coordinates of the top left corner.

I know that the scale origin is the center of the rectangle.

To find the width and height I simply did this calculate

```
newWidth = width / 0.541667
newHeight = height / 0.541667
```

But I can't figure out how to calculate the new `x` and `y` coordinates.

Which gives me these bounds

```
height: 57.25
width: 398.4609375
x: -80.35546875 //how to find this value ?
y: 77.375 //how to find this value ?
```

Comment: I think it should be: 

newWidth = width * 0.541667 , 
newHeight = height * 0.541667

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your results make sense only if your $x$-axis goes from left to right, $y$-axis goes from top to bottom and $(x,y)$ denotes the coordinate of the top left corner of the rectangle. Such coordinate system is typically used for computer screens. In that case:

```
newX = x + width/2 - newWidth/2
newY = y + height/2 - newHeight/2
```

Check your values and you'll see that the numbers match.

Comment: X, Y coordinates are top left corner I updated my question